# usar varias versiones de jquery

Tags: jquery

quisiera saber como puedo usar varias versiones de jquery en un solo proyecto...estaba leyendo algo sobre **no_conflict** pero nose como usarlo , espero su ayuda ,gracias....(estoy usando bootstrap 4 que usa jquery3.1 y necesito algunas cosas que tienen jquery1.11 y jquery2.1.4), no hay codigo porque no tengo errores todavia ,solo quiero saber como usar varias versiones para evitar errores mas adelante

Comment: Deberías replantear tu proyecto así como lo dices suena a que no existe un plan de arquitectura y eso a la larga es terrible, no puedes sustituir las versiones viejas de jquery que mencionas por ES6?

Answer (score 1):

Sacado del siguiente [vínculo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page) puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma

```
<!-- load jQuery 1.1.3 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/jquery-1.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_1_1_3 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>

<!-- load jQuery 1.3.2 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_1_3_2 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

la cosa con el método `noConflict` es que saca todas las variables globales incluyendo `jQuery` por lo que ya no podrás utilizar la variable `$` ahoral a forma de hacerlo es como sigue:

```
// forma original (ya no servira)
$('#idElemento')
// formas con noConflict
jQuery_1_1_3('#idSelector')
jQuery_1_3_2('#idSelector')
```

de todos modos deberías **siempre** considerar migrar a la última versión de una librería